# Unable to find method [attribute] with [1] parameters

Tags: jsf, expression, httplistener

i implemented an HttpSessionListener for my JSF App.

I have a `List<HttpSession>` Object for all the active Sessions to my Application. On every SessionCreated Event I add the actual `HttpSession` to this `List`. On login i added some Attributes to the active Session and replace the modified Session in the `List`. So far so good, it's working. But now i created a PrimeFaces Datatable to display which Session is a unused Session. This means which Session doesn't have the login attribute. The Login attribute is a simple String Object.

Here is the implementation of the Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable var="sessions" value="#{applicationListener.sessions}" paginator="false" id="dt_sessions">  
    <f:facet name="header">
        Sessions
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="ID" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center" >  
        #{sessions.id}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" style="font-size: 12px; text-align: center" >  
        #{sessions.attribute(login)}
    </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Tomcat throws an HTTP 500 Stacktrace:

```
Feb 6, 2013 2:00:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw     exception [/rmlcon.xhtml: Unable to find method [attribute] with [1] parameters] with root cause
javax.el.ELException: /rmlcon.xhtml: Unable to find method [attribute] with [1] parameters
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularCell(DataTableRenderer.java:741)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:693)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:601)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I do not really understand why it is thrown.  Please can someone explain me my mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method name is [`getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29), not `attribute()`.

```
#{sessions.getAttribute(login)}
```

Remember, you're invoking a method, not accessing a property, so the `get` prefix is still mandatory.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd fix `var="sessions"` to be `var="session"`, because it concerns only one session instance, not multiple. Otherwise your code reads very confusing (i.e. it's not self-documenting).

```
#{session.getAttribute(login)}
```

Comment: Thank You. Note to myself: not everytime the autocomplete feature of NetBeans is the best way to build up expressions. I followed your advice and changed my code.

Comment: Any idea why I need quotes like this `#{sessions.getAttribute("login")}`? Otherwise the param received to bean is empty string. Using Tomcat7.

Comment: @Panu: In OP's case, `login` was a variable holding the actual attribute key. You apparently don't have such a variable and it's actually the attribute key itself. You should  then indeed "hardcode" the attribute key by quoting it. By the way, usually singlequotes are used as that works better inside HTML/JSF tag attributes which are by themselves usually enclosed in doublequotes.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround

```
<p:inputText id="valore" value="#{myBean.getValObj(0).val}" />
```

The bean is

```
public class MyBean{
    public ValObj getValObj(int idx){
    return new ValObj(this, idx);
    }

    public class ValObj{
        MyBean bean;
        int idx = -1;
        public ValObj(MyBean bean, int idx){
            this.bean = bean;
            this.idx = idx;
        }

        public double getVal(){
            return valori[idx];
        }
        public void setVal(double val){
            valori[idx] = val;
        }
    }
}
```